# Storing answers to questionnaire in Django model

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a django model that should store users's answers to a questionnaire. There are many types of questionnaires, but one could be simple like this (many are more complicated though):

```
What is your name?
What is your age?
What is your height?
What is your age?
```

I want to know how I could create a model to store the data that was submitted in the form. Right now, I am using a simple JSON field like this:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
data = JSONField(default=dict)
```

This gets difficult however when the questionnaire get much longer. What would be the best way to do this? If a JSON field is the best way, how should I structure the json assuming there could be different types of questions (input field, multiple choice, etc.)? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with JSONField in postgres, main thing to keep in mind is disk space. Since, in JSON we have to store both key and value as compared to a normal field where key is already defined and we don't have to store it in every row. So basically what you can optimize is key which I think can be an id of question number rather than complete question.

Basically, You can have question model as follow:

```
Question(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and you can have your JSON data as follow:

```
{
    <question_id_1> : "Answer 1",
    <question_id_2> : "Answer 2"
}
```

This will save a lot of space, although you will have to do a mapping after fetching data but it will be less pressure on your database and more efficient. Since, you don't have fixed type of answer type, you can just save value in JSON and later infer its sense based on question_type, for e.g. whether answer value is a id value of multi choice answer field or just a sentence as an answer. For that you can have a type field in question, that will help you with that after fetching results.

Another thing you can do is rather than storing it in JSON Field, you can have a different table where you have foreign key to question as follow:

```
Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey("Question", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="answers")
    content = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think this makes sense, but how would it work if the question is a multiple choice vs. and input field. How would this change the Question and Answer models? Thanks!

Comment: Just wanted to follow up! Really appreciate your help!